# Qt: how to make decorated rich popup window instead the default QSystemTrayIcon popup window

Tags: c++, qt, trayicon

I have simple notification application, and I'm using Qt 4.7.1 with C++ to write an application that sits in the system tray. Every time a message comes; I need it to pop-up a window. But, I need it to be rich (i.e., I want to add color and pictures to it). However, all I have is the default pop-up message box. How can I create new richer one that will always pop-up above the tray icon?

Comment: To clarify, are you asking about styling the balloon notification that can be displayed using QSystemTrayIcon::showMessage() or styling a custom widget of some kind?

Comment: +1 for answering an "or question" with simply "yes".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All the qt widget classes can be styled via [stylesheets](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/stylesheet-reference.html), depending where create your popup (designer, or in code) assign it a stylesheet with the look that you want it to have. You can test stylesheets in designer by assigning a style to a widget using the context menu of the widget

After further review, the `QSystemTrayIcon::showMessage()` call puts up a *system* notification. Which I don't know if it can be styled. The `qsystemtrayicon_win.cpp` file in the qt distribution shows a workaround  and shows a way of how to find the location of the icon in the tray (see `QSystemTrayIconSys::findIconGeometry`). Once you have the location you could pop up your own window at that location. I did not look to deep, I don't know if you can get to the location for the icon with the information that you have on the public side of Qt. You might have to go all windows with that.

Comment: interesting... I didn't know that  popup could be styled. Have u ever managed to do this?

Comment: Depends on what class you are talking, there is no QPopup, but QWidget, QFrame, QMenu and so forth can all be styled. I have written an application that does very little custom drawn but uses all the standard components, even QTableView and not look like a Qt App  at all

Comment: its not so easy to do this is why im asking , some suggest to inherit and re implement show message again this is not easy or possible

Comment: It comes down to how important is it for you to have a private styled popup, is it worth the effort you will have to go through

Comment: funny question,sure i need styled more then styled i need to add more options to it like displaying more then 1 image